# bounding absolute fluctuations of random variable distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

I have a discrete random variable with values $\underline{y} = (y_1, y_2, \dots , y_d)$ with corresponding probabilities $\underline{x} = (x_1, x_2, \dots , x_d)$ and average $Y = \sum_i x_i y_i$. Some values deviate more than a fixed amount $c$ from the average, i.e. $y_1 - Y > c$ or $y_3 - Y < -c$. I want to build a new distribution (without changing the probabilities $\underline{x}$) such that all $y_i$ are within $\pm c$ of the average $Y$, in the following way; If a value satisfies $|y_i-Y|>c$ I replace it with a value that saturates that bound, i.e. $y_1 \rightarrow Y+c$. However, every time i do this the average changes, and I want it to decrease every time I saturate a bound. Is there a nice way of doing this? For example, a nicer way of finding which variables to bound without simply trying each one and recalculating the average and seeing if all other variables now obey the $c$-bound?

Comment: Do you want to *only* change the extreme values? If so then you will have to change some of them by more (or maybe less) than the amount required to "clamp" them in order to preserve the average. Or is it instead OK if the average changes, but you want the final deviation of each value from the final average to be less than $c$?

Comment: Thats correct, the values that don't lie outside of the bounds (which shift every time a bound is saturated) remain unchanged. At the end, all values that were clamped are exactly $\pm c$ deviation from the new average, and all others are unchanged.

Comment: Is it crucial that the clamped values are exactly $c$ away from the new average? Allowing for a small discrepancy here, even if can only go to one side, would make your problem drastically simpler.

Comment: To get a better idea of how you think about the modeling behind the problem, explain how you would handle a data set with ten zeros, a 2, and a 10, with $c=1$. It doesn't have to be with a well-defined algorithm.

Comment: I would be very keen to here the simple solution. The reason that its crucial that the clamped values saturate their bounds is that this problem solves a convex optimisation problem whose solution is not a closed form (and I am looking for nice inequalities / algorithms for using this solution). Ideally I want a nice way of computing it for arbitrary dimensions. The solution for $d=2$ is very easy, you always bound the least likely fluctuation! (or bound none)

Comment: So in the example I cooked up, greedy clamping will turn the $10$ into a $2$ so that we will have completely forgotten it was larger at all. That seems like a significant loss at the modeling level, to me. But I am still a bit concerned about getting stuck in an infinite descent if you proceed one component at a time and need your constraint to be satisfied with equality.